# Impedir usuários não logados de acessar páginas

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe chamada "account" e seus métodos são as páginas que o usuário logado pode acessar, ex:

```
Class account {

function info (){
//bla bla
}
function post () {
// bla bla
}

}
```

e para cada método que o usuário for acessar, eu tenho que fazer um condicional para verificar se a sessão dele está ativa, ex:

```
if($userLogged){
//deixar acessar
} else {
//redireciona
}
```

Existe alguma de forma de fazer uma única verificação para todos os métodos? algo como um construct, para qualquer método que fosse instanciado a verificação já seria feita e tratasse de dar acesso ou redirecionar o usuário.

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

É seguro fazer um simples construct para isso? ex:

```
function __construct() {

        if (!$userLogged)
            die('blabla');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar o metodo magico: `__call` que é ativado sempre que tentar aceder a alguma função da classe.